# JavaScript Charts from JSON using AJAX in Cordova

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, cordova, canvasjs

I am new to `Cordova`, i am using `canvas Js` for displaying data in chart. Following this [tutorial](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/javascript-charts-from-json-data-api-and-ajax/) i created a `Json` file and inserted the same data as it is mentioned in the tutorial, followed each step and run the code things work perfect as shown in the bellow image.

[image]

Now i want to display `datetime` on `xAxis`, for this i followed this [tutorial](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/xvaluetype/) and i am able to view the chart with date time on xAxis as shown in bellow image

[image]

But when i insert the same date time format in my json and want to see my chart the chart is empty, bellow is my json data

```
[
  [ 1088620200000, 71 ],
  [ 1104517800000, 65 ],
  [ 1112293800000, 72 ],
  [ 1136053800000, 52 ],
  [ 1157049000000, 49 ],
  [ 1162319400000, 62 ],
  [ 1180636200000, 78 ],
  [ 1193855400000, 55 ],
  [ 1209580200000, 22 ],
  [ 1230748200000, 65 ],
  [ 1241116200000, 100 ],
  [ 1262284200000, 58 ],
  [ 1272652200000, 74 ],
  [ 1291141800000, 79 ],
  [ 1304188200000, 58 ]
]
```

Bellow is my `javascript` code

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
        var dataPoints = [];
        $.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: value[0], y: parseInt(value[1]) })
            });
        });
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("container", {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            zoomType: "xy",
            animationEnabled: true,
            animationDuration: 2000,
            exportEnabled: true,

            title: {
                text: "Energy vs Date Time"
            },
            axisY: {
                title: "EnergykWh",
                interlacedColor: "#F8F1E4",
                tickLength: 10,
                suffix: "k",
            },
            data: [
                {
                    type: 'column',
                    xValueType: "dateTime",
                    //xValueFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    name: "series1",
                    legendText: "EnergykWh",
                    dataPoints: dataPoints
                    //    [
                    //                { x: 1088620200000, y: 71 },
                    //                { x: 1104517800000, y: 55 },
                    //                { x: 1112293800000, y: 50 },
                    //                { x: 1136053800000, y: 65 },
                    //                { x: 1157049000000, y: 95 },
                    //                { x: 1162319400000, y: 68 },
                    //                { x: 1180636200000, y: 28 },
                    //                { x: 1193855400000, y: 34 },
                    //                { x: 1209580200000, y: 14 },
                    //                { x: 1230748200000, y: 34 },
                    //                { x: 1241116200000, y: 44 },
                    //                { x: 1262284200000, y: 84 },
                    //                { x: 1272652200000, y: 4 },
                    //                { x: 1291141800000, y: 44 },
                    //                { x: 1304188200000, y: 11 }
                    //]
                }
            ]
        });

        chart.render();
    });
```

In above code there is a `commented` section in `dataPoints` which is the same as in my Json, when i remove the comment mark and run the code i can see data in chart perfectly, but when i want to retrieve it from `json` file i won't be able to see any thing on chart

I must be missing some thing, any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to store `json` data into a `javascript` file while storing data into a variabe and then include it in your `html` page. After that use the variable, which is in the `.js` file, and perform a `for loop`, this for loop will get your data and then you can view it in chart(s). See bellow code for more understanding.

**Save the json data into javascript file**

```
var jsonData = [{ "x": "2016-06-25 12:58:52", "y": 10.22 }, { "x": "2016-14-25 14:42:47", "y": 24.73 },
            { "x": "2016-07-25 13:33:23", "y": 11.14 }, { "x": "2016-15-25 15:07:26", "y": 26.58 },
            { "x": "2016-08-25 13:49:18", "y": 13.58 }, { "x": "2016-16-25 15:14:49", "y": 27.66 },
            { "x": "2016-09-25 13:55:01", "y": 15.25 }, { "x": "2016-17-25 15:32:51", "y": 28.68 },
            { "x": "2016-10-25 14:00:15", "y": 17.25 }, { "x": "2016-18-25 15:40:32", "y": 30.73 },
            { "x": "2016-11-25 14:23:31", "y": 19.99 }, { "x": "2016-19-25 15:58:07", "y": 32.46 },
            { "x": "2016-12-25 14:30:36", "y": 21.78 }, { "x": "2016-20-25 16:21:25", "y": 34.79 },
            { "x": "2016-13-25 14:34:23", "y": 23.45 }];
```

**Include your javascript file in html page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json.js"></script>
```

**Use a for loop to get x and y data**

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
           dataPoints.push({
              x: new Date(jsonData[i].x),
              y: jsonData[i].y
          });
        }
```

**Pass this dataPoints in canvasJs**

```
     data: [
            {
                type: 'column',
                xValueType: "dateTime",// no use for it
                //xValueFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD",// use xValueFormat 
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "series1",
                legendText: "EnergykWh",
                dataPoints: dataPoints

            }
        ]
```

I hope this will works